# how to share codes between two devices?

Tags: python, macos, server, window

I want to find a way that I can write some python code on my windows computer, and write continuously of these codes after I go back home on my mac computer. I am trying to set up a jupyter server on my windows, but I failed. Is there any other way that I can do this?

Comment: Use git and github.

Comment: git is the easiest way, but don't do it with your work code unless you intend to get paid to work continuously on it!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Codespaces](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/getting-started/quickstart), basically it creates a codespace and keeps your code in a GitHub repository, you can access, and run the code through a web version of VS code, or you can clone it, revise it, and then push it.